# Reliable time measurements with cloud high-performance computing

Tags: performance, cloud, hpc

I conduct research of graph search algorithms. In this research, the ability to reliably (i.e. re-producibly) measure the running time of a *single-threaded* program in order to compare the running-time performance of two algorithms is of paramount importance. The running time is measured inside the program (written in C++) and does not include any access to secondary storage (which happens only during the initial input phase). I used to have access to dedicated nodes of a real (i.e. non-cloud) HPC cluster. I recall that, when I ran my program on such a node twice (with the same input), I got time measurements that differed by a small fraction of a percent. The question is: can I get such reliable time measurements on a cloud HPC platform?

To substantiate the question more, for some algorithms and problem instances, my program may use a large amount of memory (say, 64GB). If I understand correctly, even cloud platforms that promise dedicated cores without hyper-threading and dedicated memory, would construct a virtual machine to satisfy such a memory requirement. The nodes making up that virtual machine may be different between the two runs, resulting in different communication overheads and, as a consequence, different time measurements. So, to repeat the question: can I get reliable time measurements on a cloud HPC platform?

Answer (score 1):

Based on discussions and experiences described in [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/igorpag/2014/11/11/azure-a-series-d-series-and-g-series-consistent-performances-and-size-change-considerations/) 
and [here](https://www.pythian.com/blog/comparing-cpu-throughput-of-azure-and-aws-ec2/) it seems to be safe to say that you should not expect measurements to always be similar.

Though, I think that depending on the number, duration of the tests, and allocation/deallocation of tests VM between test runs you could achieve accepted degree of reliability.

Comment: Thank you for the great pointers. These articles are specific to the *Microsoft* platform, which may spell portability issues for programs developed under *Linux*.